# UIButton does not diplay text set with [UIButtonname setTitle]

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

For the following code (where the UIButton is not connected to an IBOutlet):

```
UIImage *defaultButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StandardButton.png"];
PlayButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 50, 220, 50)];
[PlayButton setImage:defaultButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[PlayButton setTitle:@"PlayButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[PlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(StoryModeReleased:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:PlayButton];
```

The PlayButton pointer is declared in the .h file. The button text does not appear when I use this code, but the button displays whith the image. How can I make the text display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
PlayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIImage *defaultButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"StandardButton.png"];
PlayButton.frame = CGRectMake(250, 50, 220, 50)];
[PlayButton setImage:defaultButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[PlayButton setTitle:@"PlayButton" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[PlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(StoryModeReleased:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:PlayButton];
```

I think you forgot about declare the type of the button

Comment: I declared the type and I couldn't set the title if I used an image (I used the costume type)

Comment: I found the answer (for future reference). You have to set the backgroundImage, not the image